# react native how to re render refresh screen on tabBarOnPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

the screen  do not get the new data until i close the app and open it again

i want to re-render the screen on tab press to refresh the screen and get the new data

Please see my below code

```
const DashboardTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({

    Home: { screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: (
                <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30,tintColor:'white' }}
                       source={require('./assets/IconBootomTabNavigation/home_icon.png')} />
            )
        }
    },
    Category: { screen: Category,
        navigationOptions: {


            tabBarIcon: (
                <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30,tintColor:'white' }}
                       source={require('./assets/IconBootomTabNavigation/cat_icon.png')} />
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to place the code responsible for fetching the data inside `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. This way you can ensure you get the data after the initial render.

If the screens are not being re-rendered, please check [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/1335) thread. You can use [tabBarOnPress](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbaronpress) prop to call any component method.

You might also try this solution:

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return {
    tabBarOnPress: (tab, jumpToIndex) => {
      if(!tab.focused) {
        jumpToIndex(tab.index);
        navigation.state.params.onFocus()
      }
    },
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.navigation.setParams({
    onFocus: your-data-fetching-method
  })
}
```